# Upgraded computer, now it turns off randomly / won't turn on

Tags: windows-7, memory, ssd, power-supply, hardware-failure

I have recently upgraded my computer and now it turns off at random times.  Sometimes I'll be on all day and there will be no problem. Sometimes it'll be a couple hours and it will shut off.  And sometimes, it will try turning on several times before giving up.

Specs:

- OS: Windows 7
- CPU: Core i5 2500k (not overclocked)
- mobo: Sabertooth P67
- RAM: 16 Corsair Vengeance
- GPU: EVGA GTX 770 4GB
- HDD: 1TB Western Digital
- PSU: Corsair AX 760
- H100i Water cooler and several fans

I upgraded from:

- 8GB of RAM
- No SSD
- EVGA GTX 560
- Corsair TX750 PSU

I upgraded by BIOS from 15xx to the most recent one and that didn't solve anything either.

Comment: Is the computer stable and stay on in safe mode? Looks like you upgraded RAM, GPU, PSU and added an SSD. Try going back to original configuration. Ensure it is still stays on, and replace one item at a time (remember to remove drivers). If no issue after the first item, add the next. You could have bad ram, bad GPU, bad driver....best to narrow it down with the one-by-one install.

Comment: It's turned off in safe mode a couple of times.  And I wasn't looking forward to replacing all that, but it seems like I'll have to.  Thanks.

Comment: Any BSOD? If so, what do the crash dumps say? Does EVENT VIEWER show the reason? Try MEM-TEST. I've had some issues with the Corsair RAM similar to your issue.

Comment: Sounds like it could be overheating - and remains shut to protect itself... Did you update/alter the CPU? Did you try with just 1 RAM chip?

Answer (score -1):

Have you downloaded the correct drivers for your new video card? I had a desktop at work (granted, it was a Linux one) that would do the same thing, and upgrading the drivers solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, my drivers are up to date on everything.  And something else I forgot to mention.  It worked fine right after the immediate upgrade, but it only started doing this once I added in a couple of more fans.  Removing them doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Have you tried going back to your original RAM setup? A faulty RAM stick can cause the issue you're describing. The same goes for the PSU. Also, try checking your Event Viewer logs; they can provide important clues.